# Looking for a embedded browser

Tags: java, browser, cross-platform, webbrowser-control, embedded-browser

I am looking for the embedded browser which can be embedded in my java application.
It should be a framework which can use the existing browser of OS.
It should provide the facility of accessing the various browser controls (back, refresh, stop ... ) by java code.
it should work on both window and linux.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use selenium.  it's not an "embedded browser" in the sense of something like IE where you can just embed a canvas in another app.  It will however, allow you to open actual browser windows for the browser of your choice (ie, firefox, chrome, etc...), and control it with the selinium webdriver api.

Not sure if this meets your criteria.

Comment: I actually want to embedded the browsing functionality in my application in such a way that i can control the refresh, back buttons and can hide the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Desktop Integration Components project has this - http://java.net/projects/jdic

I used it a few years ago, and unfortunately, it looks like it hasn't been updated in 2 or 3 years, but it probably still works ok.

The other option that I evaluated at the time was http://www.webrenderer.com 
It looked very good, and is apparently still a viable, supported product. The company that I worked for simply didn't want to pay for it, and went with the free, but somewhat inferior (IMHO) JDIC implementation.

If you are just looking to be able launch a native browser, without embedding it, take a look at java.awt.Destop.browse() in JDK 6 or 7

Comment: i used it but it doesn't support new browsers on linux machines and they stopped this project.